# how to use google signin button in angular.js 2.0 typescript app?

Tags: typescript, angular, google-signin

I am trying to include a Google signin button in an Angular.js 2.0 (typescript) SPA, but I don't know what's the proper way to implement the Google callback in such a way that fires something inside my Angular component.

(or alternatively, I wonder if the right way is to write a directive, but then how do I wire the callback from there?)

**Edit: adding source code**

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    gapi.signin2.render(
      "google-login-button",
      {
        "onSuccess": (user) => console.log(user),
        "scope": "profile",
        "theme": "dark",
        "onfailure": function(err){console.log("error:"+err);}
      });
    console.log("afterview: gapi started"); //this is printed 
  }
```

The initialization seems to go OK. I see the console.log and the button. I can login in a popup window but after that window closes and nothing happens. Nothing is printed in the console, either the success or the onfailure messages

Comment: More example of the code you want to add (the Google button), the component you are working with, and what you have tried will greatly increase the chances of someone answering this question for you.

Comment: hi @sean-larkin, I edited my question to include source code. thks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally discovered the issue.. as I am working with angular 2.0, I am running the lite-server that runs by default in port 3000. If you use a port different to 80, you need to add the path in the google configuration (localhost:3000).
It would help if google api returned some kind of error to diagnose the issue (how about an http 403 error code?) 
I spend two days figuring this out, so let's hope it helps others to save some time!

Comment: amazing. Also stuck for hours. Thank you!